# how to do steps on github actions workflow for frontend and backend separately within same repository?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions, angular-fullstack

I have a merchant app github repository which consist of backend and frontend packages[image]

on my .github/workflows directory I created a frontend.yml and backend.yml how can configure to run my workflow on a specific folder?

Comment: Did you check [on.<push|pull_request>.paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github actions have a `working-directory` option to declare on workflow. It specifies the working directory for all run steps.

**Specify for all Jobs:**

```
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: api
```

[Documentation: DEFAULTS.RUN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun)

This can be configured for specific jobs too. To set `working_directory` for a specific job, here is the procedure:

**Specify for specific Job:**

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: api
```

[Documentation: JOBS.DEFAULTS.RUN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun)